# DC Motor : Torque relationship to speed

Tags: electric-machine, simulink

In Matlab/Simulink there is an example of a DC Motor (power_dcmotor)

I can not understand how it converts the speed w (rad/sec) to Torque TL (Nm)

It says:" Torque is proportional to speed; TL=Bl*w ". What B and l stand for?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Torque is proportional to acceleration and the constant of proportionality is Inertia

\$T = J\dot{\omega}\$

What this model is doing is producing some frictional torque (usually denoted by B) that can be proportional to velocity.

This frictional torque appears as load torque hence the feedback. The example model really should make this clear by stating "load torque is proportional to velocity"

If you view the DC machine model there is a **TL** input & this is **"The block input is the mechanical load torque, in N.m. "**

The **m** (measurement) port outputs:

1. Speed wm
2. Armature current ia
3. Field current if
4. Electrical torque Te

Thus, the speed \$\omega_m\$ is passed through a gain block (that would have units: \$\frac{Nm}{\omega}\$) to produce a torque, which is fed into the model LoadTorque port

Comment: [Here's the documentation on the "DC machine" block](https://se.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/dcmachine.html) used in the example OPs question is about, if that is any help.

Comment: @JonRB Thank you for your answer. It really helped me to understand how it works. But still, I cannot understand how the gain value ( 0.2287) has been calculated. I also added the parameters of the dc machine in my question.

Comment: @YiannisS. its an arbitary number in this example. In practice velocity dependant losses (ie bearing) would be documented